# Could not determine the upgrade

Tags: do-release-upgrade

`do-release-upgrade` (trying to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04) fails with this message:

```
[...]
Calculating the changes

Could not determine the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This can be caused by:
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal.


Restoring original system state
[...]
```

What can I do to fix it? Is it because of `google-chrome`? If so, how do I fix that?

---

I ran `sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-all`, which seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Mine was asked first, but yeah, they look the same.