# Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 Lts does not upgrade, keeps showing error

Tags: update-manager

The update from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 LTS does not work it keeps showing me an error as could not calculate the upgrade, even when I want it to get updated from the terminal it says the same error. I did not use the beta its the final Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.I have restarted my laptop for like 5-10 times no change. Disabling the software sources also does not help. [image]

Comment: We need more info. Did you try a beta version? Are you running Ubuntu or a flavor? Did try simply restarting? At what point in the upgrade do you get this message?

Comment: Disable all added PPA on Software-Sources, then `sudo -s`; Then: `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade; do-release-upgrade -d; exit`

Comment: @onrea I have [the same problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449374/could-not-determine-the-upgrade?noredirect=1#comment590382_449374), but doing that didn't help. Also, should `do-release-upgrade` have the `-d` option? I thought that was just for developer releases.

Comment: yes, for _devel_. You can remove it.

Comment: Also, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't do much on its own. It just finishes with `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`.

Comment: Okay, I answered [my question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449374/could-not-determine-the-upgrade/449699#449699). It's moved past the original issue, and I'm downloading the next bit now.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the same problem running

```
sudo apt-get remove libaccount-plugin-google
```

How I have found this? I have checked the last error from my "/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log" and it was related to unmet dependency of libaccount-plugin-google

I have no idea if this works for you also. gl&hf