# Unable to upgrade to 14.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, kubuntu, nvidia-optimus, 14.04

I am trying to upgrade from Kubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. When I start the distribution upgrade, I get this message after "setting new software channels":

> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade [...]

After looking on other posts, I have found that this may be due to conflicting packages. So I ran grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log and got this:

```
Broken cups-filters:amd64 Conflicts on foomatic-filters [ amd64 ] < 4.0.17-1ubuntu1 > ( universe/text )
Broken libharfbuzz0b:amd64 Conflicts on libharfbuzz0a [ amd64 ] < 0.9.19-1 > ( libs )
Broken libharfbuzz0b:amd64 Conflicts on libharfbuzz0a [ i386 ] < 0.9.19-1 > ( libs )
Broken libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 Breaks on libcogl12 [ amd64 ] < 1.14.0-2 > ( libs )
Broken libqt5core5a:amd64 Breaks on libqt5core5 [ amd64 ] < 5.0.2+dfsg1-7ubuntu11.1 > ( libs ) (< 5.2.0+dfsg~)
Broken libmuonprivate2:amd64 Breaks on libmuonprivate1 [ amd64 ] < 2.1.3-0ubuntu0.2 > ( kde )
Broken libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 Depends on libwayland-egl1-mesa [ amd64 ] < none -> 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 > ( libs ) (>= 10.0.2)
Broken libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 Depends on libwayland-egl1 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken kde-window-manager:amd64 Depends on libwayland-egl1-mesa [ amd64 ] < none -> 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 > ( libs ) (>= 10.0.2)
Broken kde-window-manager:amd64 Depends on libwayland-egl1 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken kde-workspace:amd64 Depends on kde-window-manager [ amd64 ] < 4:4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1 -> 4:4.11.8-0ubuntu6 > ( universe/x11 ) (>= 4:4.11.8-0ubuntu6)
Broken kde-workspace:amd64 Depends on kde-window-manager-active [ amd64 ] < none -> 4:4.11.8-0ubuntu6 > ( universe/x11 ) (>= 4:4.11.8-0ubuntu6)
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 Conflicts on jockey-common [ amd64 ] < 0.9.7-0ubuntu15 > ( admin )
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 Conflicts on jockey-common [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 Conflicts on jockey-kde [ amd64 ] < 0.9.7-0ubuntu15 > ( admin )
Broken ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 Conflicts on jockey-kde [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 Conflicts on libopencl1 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-input-synaptics:amd64 Breaks on kde-config-touchpad [ amd64 ] < 0.8.1-1ubuntu4.1 > ( x11 ) (< 0.8.1-2~)
Broken wine1.6-i386:i386 Depends on libopencl-1.1-1 [ i386 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken kubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on kde-window-manager [ amd64 ] < 4:4.11.5-0ubuntu0.1 -> 4:4.11.8-0ubuntu6 > ( universe/x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken libcogl-pango12:amd64 Depends on libcogl12 [ amd64 ] < 1.14.0-2 > ( libs ) (>= 1.13.4)
Broken libvlccore5:amd64 Depends on vlc-data [ amd64 ] < 2.0.8-1 -> 2.1.2-2build2 > ( universe/graphics ) (= 2.0.8-1)
Broken libperl5.14:amd64 Depends on perl-base [ amd64 ] < 5.14.2-21build1 -> 5.18.2-2ubuntu1 > ( perl ) (= 5.14.2-21build1)
Broken wine1.5-i386:i386 Depends on wine1.6-i386 [ i386 ] < 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1 -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140317.bdc41204-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140331.5c0623b5-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken wine1.6:amd64 Depends on wine1.6-i386 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none ) (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
Broken wine:amd64 Depends on wine1.6 [ amd64 ] < 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1 -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken wine:amd64 Depends on wine1.7 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken playonlinux:amd64 Depends on wine [ amd64 ] < 1:1.7.16-0ubuntu1~saucy1 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken playonlinux:amd64 Depends on wine-unstable [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken wine1.5:amd64 Depends on wine1.6 [ amd64 ] < 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1 -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140317.bdc41204-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140331.5c0623b5-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken wine1.6-amd64:amd64 Depends on wine1.6:any [ amd64 ] < none > ( none ) (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken wine1.5-amd64:amd64 Depends on wine1.6-amd64 [ amd64 ] < 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1 -> 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/otherosfs )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140317.bdc41204-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140317.bdc41204-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140331.5c0623b5-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140317.bdc41204-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140331.5c0623b5-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl [ amd64 ] < 0.6.0+git20140313.a4fbc773-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-radeon [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140317.bdc41204-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-mach64:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-15 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-r128:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-15 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-intel:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-ati:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-radeon:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-nouveau:amd64 Depends on xorg-video-abi-14 [ amd64 ] < none > ( none )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-ati [ amd64 ] < 1:7.3.99+git20140317.bdc41204-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-intel [ amd64 ] < 2:2.99.911+git20140331.5c0623b5-0ubuntu0ricotz~saucy > ( x11 )
Broken xserver-xorg-video-all:amd64 Depends on xserver-xorg-video-nouveau [ amd64 ] < 1:1.0.10+git20140220.480f0998-0ubuntu0sarvatt~saucy > ( x11 )
```

Do I have to remove all these packages manually before upgrading? I have xorg-edgers and bumblebee/primus (for my optimus card) installed and I do not want to break the system. I have also never had this kind of problems installed and I always use other repos... What is the solution for this?

Comment: Before upgrading, run full upgrade: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: That didn't work: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. System seems to be up to date.

Comment: Also if you have any PPA enabled, try to disable them before upgrading.

Comment: Just tried that now. Disabled every PPA I have and still the same error message.

Comment: I was getting a similar message yesterday. Tried again today, the upgrade worked.

Comment: Tried it again today and still the same error. I will try again later and see what happens!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same problem as you. After contending with the **/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log** I was able to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.10.

I inspected the apt.log file looking for 'Unfixed' packages. Hereafter, a sample output where the  **pkgProblemResolver** was able to find a fix :

```
Broken libqt5core5a:amd64 Breaks on libqt5core5 [ amd64 ] < 5.0.2+dfsg1-7ubuntu11.1 > ( libs ) (< 5.2.0+dfsg~)
  Considering libqt5core5:amd64 -1 as a solution to libqt5core5a:amd64 200

  Added libqt5core5:amd64 to the remove list
  Fixing libqt5core5a:amd64 via remove of libqt5core5:amd64
  MarkDelete libqt5core5 [ amd64 ] < 5.0.2+dfsg1-7ubuntu11.1 > ( libs ) FU=0
```

When it is not the case, you can remove the package if you do not need it. It turned out that in my case,  the solution was:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-all
```

It could be the solution to your problem (see your apt.log last line) as well as for other users as stated in this [related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449374/could-not-determine-the-upgrade)

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this worked and I'm upgrading as I write this. What is this package even for anyway? There were no dependencies and if it's just a dummy package then why would it stop an upgrade?

Comment: Perfect. I couldn't upgrade from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 because ppa-purge xorg-edgers was not working. This is the fix!