# Upgrading from 14.04 to 15.10 fails - can not calculate the upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10, 15.10

This is not a duplicate because this has not been answered.

Because 14.10 no longer exists, I am unable to upgrade to 15.10. The reason why I would like to upgrade is because 14.04LTS is very slow and not stable on my hardware. I have installed 15.10 on a different PC and it works great. Plus a live CD of 15.10 runs well on the PC I am having issues with.

Is there a way to manually upgrade using a live CD of 14.10 and has anyone tried this?

When I try to update using terminal this is what happens: [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2d8c5z6389m94c7/Terminal?dl=0)

Comment: Any hints from `grep ERROR /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` and `tail -n 100 /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` ?

Comment: Also check http://askubuntu.com/questions/541246/unable-to-upgrade-from-14-04-to-14-10-cannot-calculate-upgrades and http://askubuntu.com/questions/360293/could-not-calculate-the-upgrade-what-happened

Comment: What is your reason for not doing a clean install of 15.10 (after backing up your personal files & data)?

Comment: If I cannot upgrade using a live CD, I may do a clean install. I have a lot of data to back up and it takes a long time to do so. I wondered if anyone ever upgraded using a live CD to 14.10, then it should be possible to upgrade in the usual way after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there is way to do a manual upgrade, if you don't know what exactly are you tweaking, you will end up with a **broken system**, which happens quite often.

I would recommend you to use your **14.04** for a bit longer, I myself use 14.04 and I only use *LTS versions*, packages are more stable and more relevant tutorials that way.

14.04 has 5 years of support, 16.04 will come out this year. So, wait a bit, and upgrade from 14.04 LTS to **16.04 LTS** which is possible.

Comment: I wondered if anyone has upgraded using a live CD. If so, I could upgrade to 14.10 first using the live CD, then upgrade normally afterwards. I wanted to upgrade because my PC is unstable using 14.04LTS, constant crashes, etc. I have proven out hardware. Worst case I'll have to wait rather than breaking my system. Cheers

Comment: thats why i always have a clonezilla backup of the partition,then if something goes wrong which certainly will  i can go back to the way things were,like some days back even uninstalling wine showed that some packages are orphaned so i did apt-get autoremove and that remove dependencies of the desktop environments even cinnamon and gnome was not working